# Caffe stuck at iteration 0

Tags: machine-learning, neural-network, caffe

I'm implementing a domain-adaption project with CPU-only Caffe. It stuck at iteration 0 during the training process. This is what I get:

```
I0326 18:14:51.217656  9257 net.cpp:693] Ignoring source layer concat_data
I0326 18:14:51.218354  9257 net.cpp:693] Ignoring source layer slice_features_fc7
I0326 18:14:51.218359  9257 net.cpp:693] Ignoring source layer source_features_fc7_slice_features_fc7_0_split
I0326 18:14:51.218361  9257 net.cpp:693] Ignoring source layer target_features_fc7_slice_features_fc7_1_split
I0326 18:14:51.218364  9257 net.cpp:693] Ignoring source layer source_features_fc8_fc8_source_0_split
I0326 18:14:51.218365  9257 net.cpp:693] Ignoring source layer softmax_loss
I0326 18:14:51.218366  9257 net.cpp:693] Ignoring source layer fc8_target
I0326 18:14:51.218369  9257 net.cpp:693] Ignoring source layer mmd_loss_fc7
I0326 18:14:51.218369  9257 net.cpp:693] Ignoring source layer mmd_loss_fc8
I0326 18:17:06.733678  9257 solver.cpp:407]     Test net output #0: lp_accuracy = 0.0301887
I0326 18:17:34.953090  9257 solver.cpp:231] Iteration 0, loss = 4.42734
I0326 18:17:34.953160  9257 solver.cpp:247]     Train net output #0: fc7_mmd_loss = 0 (* 1 = 0 loss)
I0326 18:17:34.953181  9257 solver.cpp:247]     Train net output #1: fc8_mmd_loss = 0 (* 1 = 0 loss)
I0326 18:17:34.953202  9257 solver.cpp:247]     Train net output #2: softmax_loss = 4.42734 (* 1 = 4.42734 loss)
I0326 18:17:34.953223  9257 sgd_solver.cpp:106] Iteration 0, lr = 0.0003
```

System: Ubuntu 16.04 
Command line:

```
./build/tools/caffe train -solver models/DAN/amazon_to_webcam/solver.prototxt -weights models/bvlc_reference_caffenet/bvlc_reference_caffenet.caffemodel
```

Solver.prototxt:

```
net: "./models/DAN/amazon_to_webcam/train_val.prototxt"
test_iter: 795
test_interval: 300
base_lr: 0.0003
momentum: 0.9
lr_policy: "inv"
gamma: 0.002
power: 0.75
display: 100
max_iter: 50000
snapshot: 60000
snapshot_prefix: "./models/RTN/amazon_to_webcam/trained_model"
solver_mode: CPU
snapshot_after_train: false
```

Comment: check your input layer. does it produces batches as expected? what input layer are you using?

Answer (score 0):

Stuck at iteration 0 means that the training is waiting for input on a channel that successfully opened.  (Failing to open the channel would produce an error message, at least a time-out problem.)

You need to debug your input flow.  If nothing else, put some debugger breakpoints (or even print statements) to check that you're reaching critical parts of the flow.

Comment: I'm new to Caffe so could you be more specific about how to debug my input flow? Thanks!

Comment: No, I can't, because: (1) that's an answer too long for the Stack Overflow format; (2) the answer gets into tutoring-level discussion, which is outside the SO guidelines; (3) I've never had to do it myself: I have a co-worker who's a wizard at spotting those problems.

Answer (score 0):

Eventually, My question has nothing to do with input flow. It's just CPU mode is too slow to train the network. So if you have the same problem, it doesn't hurt to try on a GPU version Caffe. Problem closed.